# error when making GET request to 'http://localhost:3000/' “Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ... delete.js”

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting an error saying "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ... delete.js" when I try to GET '/' via my express server. This generally happens when I try to submit a form from http://localhost:3000/add and a redirect is made to '/' using `res.redirect('/')`.
here is the code in question where the redirect is being made:

```js
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  const products = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/products.json`, 'utf-8'),
  );
  const newProduct = req.body;
  newProduct.id = createProductId();
  newProduct.organic = !!newProduct.organic;
  products.push(newProduct);
  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${__dirname}/products.json`,
    JSON.stringify(products, null, 2),
    'utf-8',
  );
  return res.redirect('/');
});
```

and here is the HTML file where `delete.js` is being loaded:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all-products">
    {%PRODUCT_CARDS%}
</div>
<a href="/add">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
</a>
<script src="js/delete.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant(!) code to your question or it's going to get closed really fast.

Answer (score 1):

If add a proxy to the root "/", then when your page loads and the browser request for delete.js, instead of node serving the files, it redirects that request too.

it is better to proxy sub-urls like '/api', so if you want to make a request from the frontend, you  do app.post('/api/add...')

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by adding a proxy to the root. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Did you configure a proxy to redirect requests from the app to your server?

Comment: I didn't. I am very new to node, so I don't know much about it yet. Could you please direct me to right resources.

Comment: Also for the context, `/add` points to a GET method for a form which then submits using post request